# my process doesn't go to the child process

Tags: pthreads, pipe, ipc

I have to take a user input number 'n' in the parent process and then pass it to the child process.The child process then takes 'n' user input values and stores them in an array.It then call a thread and send this array as an argument.The thread sums all the values in the array and send  it back to the child process which prints it.

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   #include<unistd.h>
   #include<sys/types.h>
    #include<pthread.h>
    #include<fcntl.h>

   void *sum(void *a)
 {printf("in thread" );
int * arr=(int *)a;
int i;
int sum=0;
int size=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    sum=sum +arr[i];
}
pthread_exit(sum);
 }
int main()
{
int pipefd[2];
pid_t childpid;
pthread_t tid;

pipe(pipefd);
int r;
int n;

childpid=fork();


if (0==childpid)
{


    printf("in child process" );
    close(pipefd[1]);
    read(pipefd[0],r,sizeof(int));

    close(pipefd[0]);
    int *ret;
    int a[r];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <r; i++)
    {   printf("enter values: ");
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }



    pthread_create(&tid,NULL,sum,(void *)a);
    pthread_join(tid,(void *)&ret);
            printf("%d",*ret );


}
else
{   printf("in parent process" );
printf("enter a number" );
    scanf("%d",&n);
    close(pipefd[0]);
    write(pipefd[1],n,sizeof(int));
    close(pipefd[1]);

}
return 0;
 }
```

I have checked this code a dozen of times and nothing seems to be wrong.The process stops after taking the value of 'n'.The child process never runs.

Answer (score 0):

Both `read` and `write` expect to receive the memory address of a buffer to use.  You need to take the address of the variables you're trying to fill.

E.g.

```
write(pipefd[1], &n, sizeof(int));
```

and

```
read(pipefd[0], &r, sizeof(int));
```

By the way, the child process most likely is running.  It's just your value for `r` is coming back as 0.  Simple debugging trick: Use `fprintf(stderr, "stuff to print");` to check your results at various stages.  You can easily verify the child process is running, for example.

Comment: okay now the scanf() in the child process won't work.'enter values' appears n times but there is no place to input these values.I put fprintf in thread function and thanks now i know that thread is atleast running

Comment: Check this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26687602/stdin-stdout-and-stderr-are-shared-between

Comment: the answer says he has never taken stdin in a child process .But my question says that i have to take user input in the child process

Comment: You can pass a file descriptor yourself.  `dup` stdin to something different.  You can either read from that or try to redup it back to stdin in the child process.

Comment: See this post for most on `dup` with stdin, etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084099/re-opening-stdout-and-stdin-file-descriptors-after-closing-them